# looking for method of inserting Amazon data into php form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, amazon-web-services

I have been looking around for help trying to fix my old system of inserting returned search results from Amazon into a form.

The way it worked was I have a PHP based form for saving book information. The user typed in the ISBN and clicked a button, then a JavaScript program generated a signed request that returned the data in XML form. The JS program used an xslt file that converted it to a json type of results that then was inserted into the form fields. The reason it all stopped working is Amazon stopped supporting any xslt requests to their server. I have been able to substitute with googleapis, but I would rather use Amazon if possible.

**EDIT:**
I'm looking at it a new way. The original way will never work again, thanks to Amazon's changes. I have found a good start on this blog: http://anchetawern.github.io/blog/2013/02/10/getting-started-with-amazon-product-advertising-api/. That lead me to making this search.php:

```
require_once('amazon_product_api_class.php');
$public = //amazon public key here
$private = //amazon private/secret key here
$site = 'com'; //amazon region
$affiliate_id = //amazon affiliate id
$itemID = $_POST["ASIN"];
$amazon = $amazon = new AmazonProductAPI($public, $private, $site, $affiliate_id);
$single = array(
  'Operation' => 'ItemLookup',
  'ItemId' => $ASIN,   //'0718177517'
  'ResponseGroup' => 'Medium,ItemAttributes,OfferFull'
  );
$result =   $amazon->queryAmazon($single);
$json = json_encode($result);
$array = json_decode($json, true);
echo json_encode($result);
```

This works exactly like I need, except it's in php, so I can't use it to fill in the form blanks. The sequence of events needs to be like this:

User opens PHP generated HTML book entry form and enters ISBN# into text field and clicks search button -> ISBN# is sent to some search function -> search function returns results -> results sorted and entered back into the original book entry form ->  user then continues to fill out form and saves it when done.

What I did was call search.php from a jquery script using this is a function:

```
$.post('search.php', {SRCHISBN: srchASIN}, function(response) {
  var items = JSON.parse(response);
  $.each(items.Items, function () {
    $("#edit-field-book-title-und-0-asin").val(this.ASIN);
  });
  $('#example').html(response);          
});
```

The $('#example').html(response); prints out (simplified version):

```
Array
(
  [Items] => Array
    (
      [Item] => Array
        (
          [ASIN] => 0718177517
            [ItemAttributes] => Array
              (
                [Author] => Mark Owen With Kevin Maurer
                [Binding] => Hardcover
                [EAN] => 9780718177515
                [ISBN] => 0718177517
                [Label] => PENGUIN BOOKS
                [Manufacturer] => PENGUIN BOOKS
                [ProductGroup] => Book
                [ProductTypeName] => ABIS_BOOK
                [PublicationDate] => 2012-01-01
                [Publisher] => PENGUIN BOOKS
                [Studio] => PENGUIN BOOKS
                [Title] => No Easy Day
              )
        )
    )
)
```

So far the only one I can get to work is $("#edit-field-book-title-und-0-asin").val(this.ASIN). I can't seem to figure out how to get further into the returned results. I need to pull out the Author, EAN, Title, etc., and insert them into my form. Maybe I don't even need the the $.each? Is there a simpler way to access the data directly from items = JSON.parse(response)?

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: Please don't provide links, insert the relevant code you having trouble with here. If your site goes away this question becomes useless for future users. Also, try and isolate what your problem is to a small code set to help narrow down a solution.

Comment: I did remove the links, and put in the code I've been testing. I only included links because the original code was quite long.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have found an answer. I don't know if this is the best or most efficient way of doing it though.

```
$.post('search.php', {SRCHISBN: srchASIN}, function(response) {
  var parsedJSON = $.parseJSON(response);
  $("#edit-field-book-title-und-0-asin").val(parsedJSON.Items.Item.ASIN);
  $("#edit-field-author-und-0-value").val(parsedJSON.Items.Item.ItemAttributes.Author);
  $("#edit-title").val(parsedJSON.Items.Item.ItemAttributes.Title);
  $("#edit-field-publisher-und-0-value").val(parsedJSON.Items.Item.ItemAttributes.Publisher);          
});
```

This does take the items from the returned Amazon data in json format, then inserts them into the blanks on my book form, like #edit-title. It works, but like I said, I don't know if it the best way. The items I need out of the returned data will always be the same, so I don't think a for next, or each loop is needed. The list of form items is longer that what I'm showing here. I just cut it short to save space.